# Unable to insert into database - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an ajax which triggers a function called which runs an update and insert query. When i check from my db, i realise only the update query is running but then, the insert query never runs. The code below also shows my `insert` query to be correct.

What could be the issue with my code  why the update query works and insert query doesn't work?

**users.php**

```
$('#click').click(function () {
        var age = 12
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url('users/demand'); ?>',
            data: '&age='+age,
            type: 'POST'
        }).done(function (result) {
           var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
            $.each(obj, function (index, element) {

              $.ajax({
              url: '<?php echo base_url('users/supply'); ?>',
             data: '&number='+element.phone+'&email='+element.email+'&age='+element.age,
              type: 'POST'
              }).done(function (result) {
                     //refresh page for changes    
              });
          });

        });

    });



function supply()
    {
       $value =  $_POST['age'];

       $query="update table SET `status` = 0 WHERE age IN ($value)";
       $this->db->query($query);

       $save_query="INSERT INTO table(`status`)VALUES ($value)";
       $this->db->query($save_query);

    }
```

Comment: because `status != age` column here `INSERT INTO table(`status`)VALUES ($value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to add this between your query**

```
$this->db->reset_query();
```

- using this your query object is reset

Like:

```
function supply()
    {
       $value =  $_POST['age'];

       $query="update table SET `status` = 0 WHERE age IN ($value)";
       $this->db->query($query);
       $this->db->reset_query();
       $save_query="INSERT INTO table(`status`)VALUES ($value)";
       $this->db->query($save_query);

    }
```

**OR**

```
function supply() {
    $value = $this->input->post('age');
    $this->db->where_in("age", $value);
    $this->db->update("table", array("status" => 0));

    $this->db->reset_query();
    $this->db->insert("table", array("status" => $value));
}
```